# current language angularjs and i18next

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, i18next

I'm using this:
https://github.com/archer96/ng-i18next

I'm only able to get the language in options (if set):

```
console.log("language: " + $i18next.options.lng);
```

How do you get the current language?
documentation says:
i18n.lng() returns current lng.

but within the context of angular $i18next.lng() doesn't exist.

I also tried:

```
console.log("language: " + $i18next.lang);
console.log("language: " + $i18next.language );
console.log("language: " + $i18next.lng);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the developer of `ng-i18next`.

`ng-i18next` uses angular's `$watch` function to look for any changes on `$i18next.options`.

This means you should change the language by setting `$i18next.options.lng` to any language you want.

Because of this, `$i18next.options.lng` always contains the current language. There is no need for `$i18next.lng()`.

Of course this will work, too: `window.i18n.lng()`

Comment: If you let it detect the browser language and don't specify the lng on initialisation than $i18next.options.lng is undefined.

Comment: Setting $i18next.options.lng to "de" for example does not reload language for me. I have to do init again in order to have page translated without refresh. Do you maybe know why?

Answer (score 3):

This is how i18next provider does it: `window.i18n.lng();`

[Check the code here.](https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next/blob/master/src/provider.js#L33)

[Edit] I know it's an old question but I was also looking for an answer and I thought it's a good idea to share my findings.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
    var language;
    /* init i18next */ 
    i18n.init(options, function(t) {
        $("body").i18n();
    /* set global language var for usage in other functions */
        var language = i18n.detectLanguage();
    });
```

To set the language add the parameter to your URL (?setLng=de), while de is your language key in the example.